# Is it possible to install node.js in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, node.js

Is there a way to install node.js in IIS7?

I have very little experience with node.js but the idea of writing server-side JavaScript intrigues me.

Comment: Node.js is its own server - just like IIS or Apache or Nginx, etc. It is likely that you may use IIS for certain requests (e.g. existing CMSes, etc) and node.js for other request types (e.g. real-time communications). They will end up on different ports, and your application will either communicate directly with each server or one server will proxy to the other (which would large defeats the point of node.js).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done. Check out the [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) project on GitHub. Scott Hanselman also has a nice [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx) about it on his blog.